# PyCharm: Intellisense or auto-complete not working with Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, pycharm

I have recently installed Python 3.5.2 then PyCharm (IDE), but intellisense or auto-complete not working in my Windows 10.

```
# Method 1: intellisense or auto-complete not working for below
city = input("Enter your City \n")
print(city)
print(city.)     *#<<<--- here not working when put a "." after "city"* variable
```

[image: Snapshot 1]

...but surprised to see that it works fine with below code:

```
myCity = "New York City"
print(myCity.upper())
```

[image: Snapshot 2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally it working now:

1. I had to install the `Python 3.4.1` for my `PyCharm 2016.3.2`
2. Go to `File` menu >> `Settings...` >> `Project: Python Programs` >> `Project Interpreter` >> now follow below screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

*...but not sure that why it was not working with Python 3.5?* ---> Thank you to @Pavel Karateev for the helpful update.

Answer (score 2):

The value that `input` may give you may have *any* type. That is, if you happen to type `{"a": 1}`, the return type of `input` will be `dict`. Test it.

So with `input` all attribute inference is moot. The completions offered are not even attributes, it seems, but expression modifiers.

If you only want to input a string value, use `raw_input`. The result should be considered a string, and attribute completion should work.

To see it work, type:

```
city_name = raw_input("What is your city? ")
city_name.l
```

Then press the completion key after the `l`; i suppose you will be offered variants like `lower()` and `lstrip()`. This would mean that PyCharm understood that `city_name` must be a string, and offers relevant methods.

Comment: Please help me with some example/screenshot? (I have just started learning python).

Comment: Just tried... but nothing good happened yet. tried with below 3 cases:
`print(city_name.l.)         #still not working`  
`print(city_name.l().)       #still not working`  
`print(city_name.l(0).)      #still not working`

Comment: @All -- If the intellisense or auto-complete works good with my friends Windows, then it should also work in my laptop, correct? **It is working partially.**

Comment: Please type `city_name.l` _and nothing more,_ then press the completion key right when the cursor stands after the letter `l`. This should trigger completion of method names that start with the letter `l`.

Comment: Not working. Please refer to below screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9o3jdoqzrmzim4d/Screenshot%202017-01-25%2023.30.13.png?dl=0

Comment: Oops. If you position the cursor on`raw_input` and press Ctrl+Q (quick documentation), what does it show? In particular, does it show the return type?

Comment: just tried... and it gives me a message: No documentation found. Screenshot:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rvhhmz9taw3dp4/Screenshot%202017-01-25%2023.54.09.png?dl=0

Comment: @HelloWorld024; Hmm! Did you try to close and reopen the project? Did you try to remove and re-add the Python interpreter in the project settings? Do you have energy-saving mode on in PyCharm on your laptop? Something must be up with the standard library type info. (I was involved in writing the relevant code in PyCharm, but it was 6 or 7 years ago.)

Comment: I googled everywhere, tested, but nothing happened while using Python 3.5, thank you for answers.

Comment: In Python 3 `input()` returns a string. This is a PyCharm bug indeed (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21350) and it's already fixed in 2017.1 EAP: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is:

I was facing the same problem because mistakenly I had turned on the Power Save Mode in PyCharm. To turn it Off go to **File -> Power Save Mode**.
It solved my issue. Thanks